# How to test if values are increasing over time?

Tags: regression, time-series, hypothesis-testing, linear

I have a dataset with mean day temperatures going back till 1960th for the place where I live. I computed the mean year temperatures and plotted it. From the plot I can conclude temperatures are rising and climate change is real :-(

Now I would like to statistically confirm what I see, i.e. that temperatures increase along a linear function. Can you please give me some pointers what kind of statistical test I'm looking for? Last time I touched statistics was at university more than 15 years ago :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply some trends and seasonality extraction [technique](https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~gido/Removal%20of%20Trend%20and%20Seasonality.pdf), and analyze the trend. The seasonality extraction can obviously only detect wave lengths shorten than a few decades. For instance, suppose that you detected than in past 50 years the temperature is increasing. Great, does it mean that it will keep doing so in next 50 years? Perhaps that would be a reasonable conclusion, but perhaps not. What if there is 200 year cycle in temperature and we're at the peak? In this case in next 100 years we'll have a decline in temperature. You will not be able to detect this in data.

I hope you're not into DIY climate "science" here. If you're interested in application of time series analysis to similar series, then Shumway Stoffer [text](https://www.stat.pitt.edu/stoffer/tsa4/) has several examples of techniques applied to "global" climate data series. They have examples in R.

Comment: _I hope you're not into DIY climate "science" here._ Don't worry, I'm just trying to find a meaningful example to refresh my statistical knowledge. Those climate data was just the first public data I could easily get.

Comment: Ok, thank you, those two terms **trend** and **seasonality** is what I was looking for :-)